# how to add more than one image in pdf file using fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

```
<?php 
include 'connection/dbconnect.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('new/'.$id.'/1.png',10,10,-220);
$pdf->Output(); $pdf1->AddPage();
$pdf1->Image('new/'.$id.'/1.png',10,10,-220);
$pdf1->Output(); 
?>
```

Here I want to add more than one image in pdf file using fpdf.
For that I write this code but it displaying only one image.
Can anyone tell me what is the problem in my code.

Comment: Can you space that code out so it's readable? It's "minified" here and that's extremely difficult to read.

Comment: Now the code has been arrange in proper format...

Comment: That's substantially less confusing, thanks.

Comment: they're probably both there, but on top of eachother. Change the coordinates (and check the [documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm))

Comment: yep Now I got What's the problem is... Thank's a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution on This Problem is

```
<?php
include 'connection/dbconnect.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('new/'.$id.'/1.png',10,10,-220);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('new/'.$id.'/2.png',10,10,-220);
$pdf->Output(); 
?>
```